Specify the number of recommendations with Disco gem
I'm working on a recommendation system by using Disco gem. I'm curious if there is a way to specify the number of recommendations when using top_items?
I've noticed it's returning the top 5 records, but I need to customise it.
ruby '3.1.0'
rails '7.2.0'
disco '0.5.0'


Okay, for anyone who might need to know. I tried to just use the count parameter and it works :)
recommender.top_items(count: 9)
